# Classic vs Modern View

Tags: sharepoint-online

Could anyone please link me (I've search and searched and could not find a suitable document) or let me know the difference/pro-cons between

Classic and modern view on sharepoint online?

Is classic view going to be taken away in short while?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following page may answer some of your questions about the difference between the classic UI and the modern UI.

The main difference between the 2 being that the modern UI is receiving new features and will eventually be migrated to in future versions.

Cheers!

https://www.2plus2.com/News/Modern-Sharepoint-UI-vs-Classic-UI.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Teper (Corporate Vice President - Office, OneDrive & SharePoint) stated recently on Twitter that Classic view will not be going away any time soon.

[image]

https://twitter.com/SharePoint/status/884459542896967680